# How to modify the slug for the default WP posts without affecting other posttypes?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, slug

How can I modify the slug for the default wp posts without affecting other posttypes?

example: `www.example.com/slug-of-post/` should become `www.example.com/blog/slug-of-post/`

I made a few custom post types where I rewrote the slug by using `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),` in the `function.php` file.

Result: `www.example.com/post-type-slug/slug-of-post`

I need the same result but for the default posts.

Thanks.

Comment: Add them to a subpage?

Comment: They are added to the subpage `/blog`, but when go to the detail of the post `/blog` is gone.

Comment: parent: `example.com/blog`
child: `example.com/name-of-blog-post`

Comment: What I'm trying to make is: `example.com/blog/name-of-blog-post`

Answer (score 0):

First, think that listing page slug and detail page parent slug can't be same.
I mean if you create Portfolio page using `/portfolio` slug and you want to add portfolio slug as a detail page like `/portfolio/post-type-name` it's not possible.

For this situation, you need to go with `/portfolios` and `/portfolio/post-type-name`

If you want to add custom slug for post detail page you will go with this plugin [Custom Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/).